# Как скрыть при печати ActiveX элемент ComboBox оставив выбранное содержимое?

Tags: excel, vba

Как скрыть при печати ActiveX элемент ComboBox оставив выбранное содержимое?
Покопался в свойствах объекта, но ничего вразумительного не нашел. Существует ли такая возможность?

Comment: Уточните задачу.  Где оставить значение?  Зачем скрывать?  Для чего эти движения?

Comment: @vikttur, При печати докумета выводится вместе с содержимым сам ComboBox - его границы и и стрелочка вниз. А меня при печати интересует только то что значение из списка, которое я выбрал в ComboBox.

Comment: Используйте проверку данных

Comment: @vikttur, простите не догоняю

Comment: Уберите combo box, вместо него в ячейке проверка данных (закладка Данные -  Проверка данных)

Comment: @vikttur, этот вариант я просматривал, проблема в том что я переключаю кнопками RadioButton Две вариации списка. Нажимаю на один RadioButton в comboBox один список, на другой RadioButton - другой. Все элементы ActiveX  и все на листе

Comment: Вариант с combobox: Ctrl+6 скрывает/отображает все объекты листа.  Нужен макрос,  который будет записывать значение в ячейку и скрывать combobox.  А с проверкой данных проще.  Список проверки данных тоже может менять.

Comment: @vikttur, уже дошло, спасибо =)